# Go, Xorm- import xorm instance from other package but will be nil

Tags: go

Why is it nil? It's been bothering me for about three hours.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "sample/db"
)

func main() {    
    println(db.Xorm)       //nil...why...?
}
```

db/xorm.go

```
package db

import (
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "xorm.io/xorm"
)

var Xorm *xorm.Engine

func init() {

    url := "user=test host=localhost password=test port=15432 dbname=test sslmode=disable"
    Xorm, err := xorm.NewEngine("postgres", url)
    _ = Xorm

    println(Xorm)           //This is not nil

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

When I define 「SampleVariable string」 in db/xorm.go and import from main.go, it will not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
Xorm, err := xorm.NewEngine("postgres", url)
```

(notice the `:=`) is creating a new local variable `Xorm` inside the `init()` function's scope that shadows the package level variable with the same name and as a consequence, the package level variable remains `nil`.

using just `=` for the assignment should fix the issue, e.g.:

```
var err error
Xorm, err = xorm.NewEngine("postgres", url)
```